# auto renew ssl certificat with certbot

Tags: ssl, dns, ssl-certificate, certbot

I have some private services behind VPN(wireguard).

I generate certificate for them with certbot and dns chalange.but I have to renew them every three month.

how can I automate this?

Answer (score 1):

Check if there is a DNS plugin for your DNS server. If one is not available, then you must replace the certificates manually.

If there is a plugin available, you will need to reissue your certificate to use automatic renewals.

[DNS Plugins](https://eff-certbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using.html#dns-plugins)